# javascript - insert content into html - maxmind geoip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a service that generates the users city based on IP. I already have a script that ads it to the value field of a hidden form field. Now I need it to be inserted into 3 different places in the html. The current script below inserts the city into a hidden form field. What I have so far:

Header:

```
 <script src="http://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
 <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="script.php">
 <input type="hidden" id="city" name="city" value="" />
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";

var getCity = function( geoipResponse ){
    var cityName = geoipResponse.city.names.en || 'your city';
    document.getElementById('city').value = cityName;
};

var fail 

= function(err) {
    alert(err.error);
    console.error(err);
}
geoip2.city( getCity, fail );
</script>
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit(); return false;" class="agree">Submit</a>
```

This submits the form fine. Now I just need to display the city somehwere in the html but I cant seem to get this to work. Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Is the issue inserting the information, or triggering it, or both?

Comment: You can't see it because you're using `<input type='hidden' />`. I would use a `<div>` and `.innerHTML` so you don't have to make it readonly, unless you must have that input for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

If you have 3 different places to display the city, use a class in an HTML element in 3 different places in your HTML. For example:

```
<div class="city-display"></div>
```

Then show it:

```
var getCity = function( geoipResponse ){
    var cityName = geoipResponse.city.names.en || 'your city';
    document.getElementById('city').value = cityName;
    $('div.city-display').text(cityName);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting here since I am unable to comment...

It looks like you have  `type="hidden"` in your input element. This is likely why you aren't seeing the cityName value appear.